# Make Custom Post Type with custom field inherit category's custom field when empty

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

been struggling finding a solution to my problem for weeks.

**Case :**
I have a custom post type named : `design`. This CPT have a custom field (made with ACF plugin) called **thematique**. I created the same custom field (**thematique**) for `design`'s categories.

**Expected behaviour:**
I want that whenever if we make a `get_posts()` or `WP_Query` if a design's **thematique** field is empty, it should inherit its categorie's **thematique**.

I've investigated into the `pre_get_posts` hook but I'm not quite sure how to handle it.

Anybody has an idea ?

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate your help !

Comment: Maybe you try to get **category** thematique field in the wrong way? [ACF - get taxonomy based field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/)

Comment: can you share you code?

Comment: I do use it the right way. Having **thematique** field on both the CPT and the category/taxonomy is intentional. It's like : if CPT's **thematique** field is filled, prioritize it on categorie's **thematique** field. If it's empty, gather CPT's category's **thematique**. Does that make more sense to you ?

Comment: @Ali_k I didn't code anything yet. I'm trying to gather suggestion first because I don't really know where to head.

Comment: Well `pre_get_posts` is the way to go, without having a piece of code I can't personally build all the logic for you. So you need to provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this the easy way and inside your WP Query where you have the formatting for each returned item add this:

```
<?php $thematique = get_field('thematique'); //Gets current posts value of fiels
<?php if (empty($thematique)){ //Checks if the field is empty, if so do the following
    $postCat = get_the_category(); //Get current posts category ID
    $catID = 'category_' . $postCat; //Merge category ID and needed string for ACF
    $thematique = get_field('thematique', $catID); //Updated the value of $thematique with categories value
}?>
```

Although not tested this should indeed work as it's how ACF says to get the value from categories. Find out [more here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/).

Answer (score 0):

@Ali_k

I'm not so sure about how to go about it though. I would need something like :

```php
// Designs Thematique priority mechanic
function design_thematique_priority($query){
    if($query->query['post_type'] == "design"){
        foreach($query->posts as $post){
            if($post->thematique == ""){
                $post->thematique = $post->category->thematique;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'design_thematique_priority' );
```

But I don't think there is any loop I can use to loop through posts in `pre_get_posts` right ?